# Laravel Global Middleware to set Country Value failed in its logic

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cookies, geolocation

Im working on a Laravel Global Middleware to set Country Value in a Cookie when web visitors access the website.

For that reason I create the following function:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!$request->cookies->has('geo'))
    {
        if (!$request->cookies->has('geo') && GeoIP()->getLocation()->iso_code !== null) {
            //find customer IP location
            $code = strtolower(GeoIP()->getLocation()->iso_code);
            // creates a cookie with iso_code value
            $cookie = cookie('geo', $code, 600);
            //move to page
            return $next($request)->cookie($cookie);
        }
        else{
            return response()->view('static.select-country');
            //move to page
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
    if ($request->cookies->has('geo')) {
        //move to page
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

1- If cookie 'geo' is null:

- First: cookie 'geo' is null and Torann GeoIp detector is not null -> create a cookie with country ISO_CODE
- Else (geo cookie is null && GeoIP detector is null) -> go to page select-country.phtml in order to choose your country and set the cookie manually.

2- If cookie geo is not null code: ($request->cookies->has('geo'))

- Visitor already has a cookie -> move to page.

(my idea for step 2 is for existing customers that already have a country (already have a cookie with that value) but they want to change manually the country in static.select-country view and avoid GeoIP detector override by loop 1.)

My problem: at this moment when customer choose manually in static.select-country view, it moves to page home:

- But the application assign a cookie with GeoIP detector instead of take into consideration manually selected country (cookie created in static.select-country) by customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a route for that selecting country page and ignore that route in above middleware. then every one can visit that page and select own country from list and set that country code in cookie.

```
if ($request->is('YOUR_ROUTE_PATH')) {
   return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: testing the proposed solution.